# Git CLI automatically delete feature branch after merge

Tags: git

In GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab you can set feature branches to be deleted after a successful merge in development. If you work locally without a remote repository, I would like to set up my git like this.

So instead of:

```sh
git checkout development
git merge feature/#123
git branch -d feature/#123
```

only:

```sh
git checkout development
git merge feature/#123
```

My idea: It must be a GitHook!?

Comment: I think this answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004284/17544035.