# How to auto delete branches if PR is closed?

Tags: github, devops, github-actions, pull-request

I know we can auto delete branches when PR gets merged on Github. Is there a way we can get branches to auto delete when PR is closed?

I do not see an option in Settings tab of Repo for deleting branches when PR gets closed

Comment: You could use an action from the marketplace ([here is one](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-delete-branch)) that delete branch. Then you could implement a workflow using this action, that would trigger only when a PR is closed, extracting the branch name automatically by using the github context variable in pull_request for the branch name which is `${{ github.head_ref }}`.

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd. I have already implemented the github action solution. I was wondering if there is a simpler solution out there. Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically delete git branch after merge to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485936/automatically-delete-git-branch-after-merge-to-master)

Comment: Hey @ThisaruG, no. I want to delete the branch when PR gets closed, not merged

Comment: I can't believe this feature doesn't exist, if that's really the case, because there's the feature to automatically delete branches from which we just merged but not to delete branches, which turned out to be useless. Incredible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no inbuilt functionality for this on Github, I used github actions for this. Here's a snippet on how we can get this done:

```
 steps:
      - name: Delete closed PR branch
        uses: dawidd6/action-delete-branch@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{github.token}}
          numbers: ${{github.event.pull_request.number}}
```

Answer (score 1):

While completing the PR, we have a Checkbox, when selected will delete the source branch as soon as we complete the PR.

[image: Complete the PR by clicking on Complete]

As soon as you click on **Complete**, there is a Checkbox for Deleting the source branch.
Select the respective Checkbox, and Click on **Complete** to complete the PR and for deleting the SOURCE branch.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Option will be showed whenever you merge the code from the PR to the target branch.

Comment: Right, but I wanted to auto delete it